# I can't play 60fps videos on youtube (720p/1080p) on chrome . They are laggy always stopping and shows the loading animation

Tags: intel, youtube

I can't play 60fps videos on youtube (720p/1080p) on chrome(or firefox) . They are laggy always stopping and shows the loading animation but my internet connection is fast ! My ultrabook is hp stream 13 and on windows 10 I can play them perfectly 100% an smooth while on Linux they can't be played at all , they lag , freeze etc . Is it a problem with Linux and intel graphics drivers ? I did everything I could do .
On chrome I have enabled video acceleration on chrome:flags installed the newest drivers etc from padoka ppa , tried a light destop environment without compositor tried everything but nothing worked, too shame on 2017 and problems like these haven't been fixed yet, I wonder if they would be solved some day in the distant future ..... very disappointed ! I'm using Linux from 1999-2000 and i have never imagined that 17 years later Linux would still have problems like these. Of course i'm not gonna install Linux on my ultrabook cause i don't appreciate an operating system that can't drive my hardware to the max performance that's the point of the operating system anyway to utilize the hardware to the max possible.

Comment: Do you want help, or do you want to complain?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is a light weight os. All linux distros are. And it really isn't supposed to be used for high end gaming. And also, watching at 60fps videos is great but why not try 30fps or lower. 
Also your drivers might not have the right updates. Mabe try updating using windows device manager.

Ok, I'm not an expert so I'm just guessing what might be good because these are the things I did and Ubuntu works great. I'm sorry that you may be dissapinted in Ubuntu, but the fact that you say Ubuntu hasn't solved these problems doesn't really make sense to me. For me, I'm using a crappy laptop and Ubuntu runs extremely fast despite me dual booting it alongside windows 10. Personally I think ubuntu has changed and improved a lot to speed things up. Sorry if I offended you or anything and thanks :)

Comment: There much work to be done on graphics drivers.

Comment: The strange is that if I play it with smplayer (it has an extension for youtube) the videos are played smoothly ! So it has something to do with the  html5 player on chrome. Can I change this on chrome or chromium ? chromium is opensource